# Oracle table row count differs when queried from the individual table and from ALL_TABS

Tags: sql, oracle11g, jira

Following two queries (executed as DBA) yield two different row counts.

```
select table_name, num_rows from all_tables where owner = 'JIRA' and table_name = 'JIRAISSUE';

select count(*) from JIRA.JIRAISSUE;
```

I know that the second query returns the correct value.

- Why does this happen? What I suspect is there are pending transactions but not so sure. (uncommited work)
- Is there any particular SQL command to 'refresh' or 'regenerate' the numbers returned by ALL_TABS?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NUM_ROWS column is only an ***estimate*** which is (only) updated when the table's statistics are updated.

And even right *after* an `DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS()` the value will **not** reflect the correct number of rows (it might, but it's not guaranteed as it is only an *estimate*)

Comment: I think you mean DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS, I don't think there is an analyze_table procedure

Answer (score 1):

If you want `all_tables` to return the accurate count, you have to analyze it like this:

```
analyze table JIRAISSUE compute statistics
```

That way, when you run your above statement, it will return the correct results.  Howver, on the next insert, it will be incorrect until you reanalyze.

Comment: No. NUM_ROWS is always an estimate. It is never guaranteed to be accurate, even right after using `dbms_stats`. `analyze table` should not be used any longer. It has been deprecated since Oracle 10

Comment: Ah, it's been a while since I've used Oracle, thanks for the clarification.  I thought compute would give accurate numbers (as of the time it ran), where estimate would only do a sampling.  Thanks again.

Comment: It's highly likely that compute gives an accurate number, but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: Thank you for both of your helpful answers @a_horse_with_no_name and @sgeddes ! I looked at the Oracle docs of `ANALYZE` statement here:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_4005.htm

`DBMS_STATS` seems to be the correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

without running the analyzer the query below gives you the correct results:

```
select
table_name,
  to_number(
    extractvalue(
      xmltype(
   dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) c from '||table_name))
      ,'/ROWSET/ROW/C')) row_count
from ALL_TABLES ;
```